# php script fails to connect to MySQL with SSL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

The script below runs on a Centos server and is trying to connect to a MySQL database on another server which requires SSL parameters. The credentials used in the script work fine using and Microsoft Access DSN connection.

```
<?php
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=99.99.199.199;dbname=dummy1', 'user1', 'pwd1', 
array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/ck.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/etc/mysql/ssl/cc.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/c1.pem'
));
$statement = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES;");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
?>
```

The code above gives **SSL operation failed with code 1** - here is the full message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): SSL operation
>   failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
>   /var/www/vhosts/zzzzz.org/httpdocs/zzodbc/dgodbc1.php:10 
>   Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/zzzzz.org/httpdocs/zzodbc/dgodbc1.php(10): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=99.9...', 'odbc_guil...', 'pwd1',
>   Array) #1 {main} Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] in
>   /var/www/vhosts/zzzzz.org/httpdocs/zzodbc/dgodbc1.php:10 Stack trace:
>   #0 /var/www/vhosts/zzzzz.org/httpdocs/zzodbc/dgodbc1.php(10): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=99.9...', 'odbc_guil...', 'pwd1',
>   Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/zzzzz.org/httpdocs/zzodbc/dgodbc1.php on line 10

I have verified that the credentials, including the SSL parameters with a DSN connection.  I have checked that the SSL Keys are correctly located in the */etc/mysql/ssl* directory.

Any help to suggest what I'm doing wrong would be good.  Thanks.

**I may have been going at this in the wrong way....**
Since these keys work with ODBC then I think I should be using using odbc_connect and sending the same string as I use with MS access such as

```
$user = "user";
$pass = "pwd";

$connection = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=46.51.178.163;Database=db1;sslca=/etc/mysql/ssl/c1.pem;sslkey=/etc/mysql/ssl/ck.pem;sslcapath=/etc/mysql/ssl/;sslcert=/etc/mysql/ssl/cc.pem";

$con = odbc_connect($connection, $user, $pass);
```

But to get this to work I need to install a MySQL connector on the server which I'm grappling with at the moment.

Comment: The Certs, did you get them from a provider, or make them yourself? they don't seem to be verified. Or there is no connection to a verification server.

Comment: Thanks Anuga - they were came from the database provider.

Comment: That doesn't help. Your connection string contains SSL settings but it doesn't explicitly state what validation should be done - i.e. maybe your ODBC connection isn't using the SSL? Have you tried testing the connection using openssl?

Comment: Thanks syncbean - it definitely uses SSL.  I got it to work by shortening the driver name and placing it in the /usr path rather than /root. I don't understand why this should make a difference but it now works!.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem -thanks for all who have helped. This is what I have learned:

- SSL keys are *connection type* specific - so I had keys that worked with ODBC and it was wrong to expect them to work with PDO
- ODBC drivers ( php extensions ) need to be installed on the server - they aren't automatically present.   [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fmo-fN4eWA) is an excellent video showing how to do this.
- You need command line access to the server to install the driver ( and also to upload the SSL keys to a secure location ) - they are in /etc/mysql/ssl.
- I installed the driver in /usr/lib/odbc2/lib rather than in the long folder name in the video.  I also installed the in the */usr tree* because when I tried the locations in the video I got file not found errors. The two driver files are **libmyodbc5a.so** and **libodbc5w.so**.  Only the ...5w.so file seems to be required.
- Once these files are in place then you need to add an entry to *odbcinst.ini* in the /etc folder.  I used nano   so the command line   *nano odbcinst.ini* brings up the file which had a model entry for PostgresSQL.  If the server is 64 bit then these are the entries I made in odbcinst.ini:
  [mysql537]
  Driver64     = /usr/lib/odbc2/lib/libmyodbc5w.so
  Setup64      = /usr/lib/odbc2/lib/libmyodbc5w.so
  UsageCount   = 1
- **You must have the ...64 paths** otherwise the driver isn't found ( i.e  Driver64 = NOT Driver=  ).  I made this mistake first off.
- Provided the driver files are found at the paths in odbcinst.ini then things should work. (I thought I needed entries in odbc.ini but I now believe you only need something here if you are using a DSN).
- the folder *odbc2* was one I created inside */etc/lib* which already exists. I did that to avoid any permission issues by creating a new folder.

Here is the code that works ( the connection string is exactly the same as the string used in a Microsoft Access connection ):

```
<?php
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$user = "odbcmmm";
$pass = "999999999";

$connection = "Driver={mysql537};Server=99.99.199.199;Database=db_name;UID=odbc_db_name;PWD=password;sslca=/etc/mysql/ssl/c1.pem;sslkey=/etc/mysql/ssl/ck.pem;sslcapath=/etc/mysql/ssl/;sslcert=/etc/mysql/ssl/cc.pem";

$con = odbc_connect($connection, $user, $pass);

$sql="SELECT Id from stk_item"; 
$rs=odbc_exec($con,$sql);

if (!$rs)   {
exit("Error in SQL");
}
```

I hope this is useful.